# Fail to load turtle files using jena assembler file

Tags: jena, apache-jena

I define an assembler file with name dataset2.ttl. The content of this file is:

```
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .

@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .
<#dataset> rdf:type         tdb:DatasetTDB ;
   tdb:location "DB" ;
   tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ;
   .

<#data1> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
    tdb:dataset <#dataset> ;
    tdb:graphName <http://example.org/data1> ;
    ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:///C:/Users/data/data1.ttl>;];
    .
```

The related jena code to create a datase is:

```
public class TDB {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dataset ds = null;
    try {
        ds = TDBFactory.assembleDataset("Dataset2.ttl");

        if(ds == null) {

            System.out.println("initial tdb failed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Default Model:");

            Model model = ds.getDefaultModel();

            ds.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
            model.write(System.out, "TURTLE");
        }
    } finally {
        if(ds != null) {
            ds.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The content in data1.ttl is:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
@prefix foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

:alice
a           foaf:Person ;
foaf:name   "Alice" ;
foaf:mbox   <mailto:alice@example.org> ;
foaf:knows  :bob ;
foaf:knows  :charlie ;
foaf:knows  :snoopy ;
.

:bob
foaf:name   "Bob" ;
foaf:knows  :charlie ;
.

:charlie
foaf:name   "Charlie" ;
foaf:knows  :alice ;
.
```

A dataset has been created using this code. However, the content in the file of "data1.ttl" has not been read into the model. What is the problem of my code?

Comment: What messages are you seeing in the console "initial tdb failed" or "Default Model:" ?

Comment: In the console it displays: "Default Model:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have

```
<#dataset> rdf:type         tdb:DatasetTDB ;
   tdb:location "DB" ;
   tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ;
   .
```

and

```
ds = TDBFactory.assembleDataset("Dataset2.ttl");
```

so you are asking Jena to assemble a dataset. That dataset will be `<#dataset>` (find by the type).  It is not connected the graph you define so that's ignored; you can remove that part. Assembling the dataset is the way to do this.

You have `tdb:unionDefaultGraph true` so the default graph for query is the combination of all named graphs in the dataset.

Pick one out with `model.getNamedModel`.

If you use SPARQL, use the `GRAPH` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would try validating your ttl file online to make sure they dataset2.ttl and data.ttl are both valid. I noticed you seem to add an extra semi-colon at the end when it's not needed (it should end with just a period).

try changing your line to this:

`ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:///C:/Users/data/data1.ttl>] .`

Comment: I have changed it as yours. However, the result is still the same.

Comment: I have updated the file of data1.ttl. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: I would also try changing the file path, try a url or a relative path and see if that works such as <file:data/data1.ttl>

Answer (score 0):

```
<#data1> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
    tdb:dataset <#dataset> ;
    tdb:graphName <http://example.org/data1> ;
    ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:///C:/Users/data/data1.ttl>;];
.
```

Note the `tdb:GraphTDB` which means attach to a graph in the database. It does not load data with `ja:content`.

As a persistent store, it is expected that the data is already loaded, e.g.by `tdbloader`, not every time the assembler is used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to load data into TDB (not memory) using an assembler file?

Comment: Could you please give me an example that the loaded data is accord with the description in an assembler file.

Comment: It is expected that the data is already loaded.  A persistent database is not for loading each time. Either use a memory graph and load it, or load the database first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently the file has been loaded into a memory graph. Then I use a dataset to store those named graphs.  However, when I query them using SPARQL named graph, the result contains all the info from the dataset, not limited in the specific named graph.